# Cassandra opscenter is not communicating with cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have 2 node Cassandra cluster with datastax-agent up and running(one seed node) also nodetool status showing healthy.

In the 3 node I have opscenter install and the UI is loading fine with a blank screen, when I saw the var log it's complaining '*NO cassandra connection available for hostlist with a invalid unsupported version*'(paster the log details message below). Any help is highly appreciated

> 2017-02-25 06:33:06+0000 [CLUSTER_NAME] ERROR: Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'SEED-IP': })
>   2017-02-25 06:33:06+0000 [CLUSTER_NAME]  WARN: No cassandra connection available for hostlist ['SEED-IP'] .  Retrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using an old version of opscenter which was not matching the version of dse. Here is the map for your refference.

[image]

Reference: [datastax doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html#compatibilityDocument__opsc-compatibility)